# focus on ion-radio using vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4, setfocus

I have a radio button in `ionic` `vue js` like this:

```
<ion-list v-if="product.size_maps">
  <ion-radio-group v-model="selectedSize">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col
        v-for="size in product.size_maps"
        :key="size.id"
        size="6"
        id="product_size"
      >
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="ion-no-margin">
            {{ size.size.text }}
          </ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" :value="size.size.id" ref="product_size"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

I want to **focus** on the radio button *if* user click `add-to-cart` button without selecting the radio

I tried using `ref` but it is not working properly

```
addToCart() {
  if (this.selectedSize > 0) {
    let orderData = {
      selectedSize: this.selectedSize,
      productId: this.product.id,
      orderQty: this.orderQty,
    };
    this.sendOrderRequest(orderData);
  } else {
    this.openToast("Please Select Size First");
    console.log(this.$refs.product_size.$el); // i can get radio button here

    // below two functions are not working
    this.$refs.product_size.$el.setFocus();
    this.$refs.product_size.$el.focus();
  }
},
```

Comment: Use `nextTick` callback: `this.$nextTick(() => this.$refs.product_size.focus())`

Comment: @YashMaheshwari It worked thanks :) but I have to use `this.$refs.product_size.$el.focus();` this. added `$el`  before `.focus()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that if you want to use `$ref` variable inside any method you need to use `$enxtTick` to access the variable

Here is the solution:

```
addToCart() {
  if (this.selectedSize > 0) {
    let orderData = {
      selectedSize: this.selectedSize,
      productId: this.product.id,
      orderQty: this.orderQty,
    };
    this.sendOrderRequest(orderData);
  } else {
    this.openToast("Please Select Size First");

    // use the $nextTick this way
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      // here you can use this.$refs, this.selectedSize, this.orderQty etc
      this.$refs.product_size.$el.focus();
    });
  }
},
```